# Triggering onChange function on Ant Design Slider in React Testing Library not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, antd, react-testing-library

I made a wrapper around the Ant Design Slider. It looks like this

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Slider as AntSlider } from 'antd';

export function Slider(props) {
  const { value, onChangeFunction } = props;

  const [currentValue, changeValue] = useState(value);

  const onChange = (newValue) => {
    onChangeFunction();
    changeValue(newValue);
  }

  return (
    <AntSlider
      value={currentValue}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  )

}
```

It's extremely simple. The only thing to note is that there is an onChange function.
I am now trying to test this component with React Testing Library. Here is an example of my test

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('Basic Test', () => {
  it('Should change', () => {
    const change = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = render(
      <Slider value={30} onChangeFunction={change} />
    )

    const slider = wrapper.getByRole('slider').parent;
    fireEvent.change(slider, 35);
    expect(change).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  })
})
```

I expect the `change` function to have been called, but this keeps failing. It seems like I am calling the `change` function in the wrong way. Is there something wrong I am doing in making this test?

Is there any way I can get the test to work? I know people say it's better to mock components, but my real components have more complicated logic in them and I'd prefer to be able to tell if the onChange function is actually getting called rather than creating a mocked component in the test file.

Comment: did you solve it? i am having the same issue. it will be great if you can share :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't. I think the correct solution, which is really not optimal, is to use [Enzyme](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/) for these types of components instead of React Testing Library. The reason is that Enzyme lets you test based on props, so you can trigger an `onChange` function that way. I already wrote a bunch of tests in React Testing Library, so I'm not completely switching to Enzyme, but I think it makes sense to switch to Enzyme for these cases.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

comp:
(cannot assign data-testid to comp itself)

```
<div data-testid='sliderWrapper'>
  <Slider
    style={{ marginLeft: '0px' }}
    min={0}
    max={1}
    onChange={handleSliderChange}
    value={sliderInput}
    step={0.01}
  />
</div>
```

test:

```
const sliderWrapper = getByTestId('sliderWrapper')
const handle = sliderWrapper.querySelector('.ant-slider-handle') as HTMLElement

fireEvent.mouseOver(handle)
fireEvent.mouseDown(handle)
fireEvent.mouseMove(handle, { clientX: 100 })
fireEvent.mouseUp(handle)
```

Comment: This gets the job done. The issue is you don't have a way to specify the value you are changing, only how many pixels you are moving the slider. I feel there has to be some better way to trigger the onChange

Answer (score 0):

My approach might be a bit radical for some but here it goes.

I don't care what ant design does under the hood, I expect their lib to be tested. I want to test my `onChange` logic. So I mock the Slider.

```js
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

jest.mock('antd', () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('antd'),
    Slider: jest.fn((props) => <button data-testid="fakeSlider" onClick={() => props.onChange('new value to test')} />),
  };
});


describe('Basic Test', () => {
  it('Should change', () => {
    const change = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = render(
      <Slider value={30} onChangeFunction={change} />
    )

    const slider = wrapper.getByTestId('fakeSlider');
    fireEvent.click();
    expect(change).toBeCalledWith(XYZ);
  })
})
```

Again, some may agree and some wont :-)